# Same Machinekey on Mono and IIS running MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, mono, nginx

Current setup:

Server A -

OS: Debian Squeeze 
Web Server: Nginx + Fastcgi + Mono 3.0 
ASP.NET MVC 4 (.Net 4.5) using base internet template. 
Db Backend: Mysql 
Domain: (example) servera.domain.com

Server B -

OS: Windows Server 2012 
Web Server: IIS8 
ASP.NET MVC 4 (.Net 4.5) using base internet template. 
Db Backend: Mysql 
Domain: (example) serverb.domain.com

Both servers are using the same machine key and the cookie is set to .domain.com. Cookie name is set to .ASPXAuth (to override the mono cookie name).

The idea is to register on Server A and to be able to login with the same details on Server B. Also if you log into Server B you should be able to browse to Server A and still be logged in. But this isn't working. I cannot login with the same details on both servers and the cookie created isn't working on both servers only one.

If I remove the machine key from both servers then I can create an account and login to both servers with these details but as the machine key isn't set the cookie created won't work on both servers.

I have tested this between two windows servers and it works fine. Is Mono doing something different with the machine key?

Any ideas?

Comment: Since mono is open source, you could easily debug it, tracing what it does when logging in with the windows-created cookie to see where it fails.

Comment: What login process are you using? If you say: "I cannot login with the same details on both servers" there is something fundamentally broken with the login process, and I doubt the machine key has anything to do with it.

Comment: Jester - I've been looking into debugging mono but I'm not completely sure on what route to take. It seems the only real way to debug it correctly is using MonoDevelop on linux itself?

Comment: Dyna - I'm just using the default MVC 4 .Net 4.5 internet template. Only changes I made was switching out the default provider for the mysql provider. If I don't set a machinekey then any users created can login from both servers. But if I set a machinekey then users created on one server cannot login to the other.